# How to run Flask application which runs in python virtual environment venv in pm2

Tags: python, flask, pm2

I am trying out ways to work with pm2 to run a flask app.

The use case is want to run a python web server in the background with auto-restart features and other useful pm2 features.

The flask app runs in a virtual python environment, so I need to do `source venv/bin/activate` for the app to work properly.

When I run the following command

```
source venv/bin/activate
pm2 start "export FLASK_APP=index.py;python -m flask run" --name flask-app --interpreter=python3
```

The app errors out

SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xcf' in file /bin/bash on line 1, but no encoding
declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

The same app runs without pm2 when I just run

```
source venv/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=index.py
python -m flask run
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Can anyone give me an example of running the flask app in a virtual environment, in the background using pm2?